# How to ssh as different user, change group, and run a script within Perl

Tags: perl

I need to be able to run a script from within a script but first I need to ssh as a different user and then change my group.

I am currently doing the following inside my perl script:

```
`ssh <user>@<host> ; newgrp <group> ; /script/to/run.pl`
```

When running this command form the command line it doesn't seam to switch groups. I assume this is because it's changing to a new shell.

How do I get around this and get it to work?

Also, please note, I do not have sudo/root privelages.

Comment: `sg $group -c '$cmd'`

Comment: This worked perfectly salva!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

salva, in his reply, answered my question:

```
sg $group -c '$cmd'
```

The reason the following command:

```
newgrp <int>
```

doesn't work is because it creates a new shell. At least that is my best guess. the "sg" command gets around this.

Comment: yes, utilities that change the current user or group (`su`, `sg`, `nwegrp`, `sudo`, etc.) always launch a new shell. It is that way because a program can't change the credentials of its parent process. It can only change its own and afterwards, have its descendants inherit them.

Answer (score 2):

The first semicolon is interpreted by the local shell. So the three commands are run on the same host.  I think you want this

```
ssh <user>\@<host> "newgrp <grp>; /bin/run.pl"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following to work (with `ksh` on `hpux`) :

```
ssh user@host "echo 'date;pwd;echo bozo;id' | newgrp nerds;"
```

which basically executes the commands as `user:nerds` :

Answer (score 0):

I think OP wants to construct a string to execute from Perl, notice the backticks. Not sure but OP might have to use:

```
$s='ssh <user>@<host> ; newgrp <group> ; /script/to/run.pl'; # Normal single quotes not backticks
exec($s);
```

OP, there are different ways to execute shell functions from a Perl script. You used backticks. There is also exec($s) and system($s).